# How to convert control m existing code to airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

We are already using the control m but we want to switch to Apache Airflow. How to convert existing control m code to airflow compatible dag? This is what I found in slide of official website but I am not getting what is “mappings” here? Can anyone explain please?

[image]

Please explain the meaning of mappings here.

Comment: Do not use photos for code. Use markup.